# capturing previous values to verify mock object

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

In mockito, is it possible to capture the previous value set to a field of an object passed to a mock object's method for example the method under test performs this

```
    public void methodUnderTest(){
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setAge(5);
    someObject.setPerson(person);

     ...

    person.setAge(6); 
    someObject.setPerson(person);
    }
```

What I wanted to know is if I mock someObject, will I be able to verify that someObject performed setPerson to a single object "person" twice but the object had different value for age when setPerson occurred? I tried using ArgumentCaptor but since I passed the same object, I was just able to get the last age.

```
    ArgumentCaptor<Integer> arg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
    verify(mockObject).setPerson(arg.capture());
    List<Integer> captureList = arg.getAllValues();
    captureList.get(0).getAge(); // returns 6
    captureList.get(1).getAge(); // returns 6
```

I also tried doing

```
    InOrder in = inOrder(mockObject);
    in.verify(mockObject).setPerson(arg.capture());
    assertEquals(5, arg.getValue().getAge()); //fails
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with an `ArgumentCaptor`.
The captor only stores a reference to the argument; in this case, it stores twice a reference to the same object, *person*.

You should try using an `Answer`, to perform the proper check every time the `setPerson` method is called.

This [mockito issue](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=126) is related to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
verify(mockedList, times(1)).setPerson(eq(5));
verify(mockedList, times(2)).setPerson(eq(6));
```

Been a while since I used mockito so I think that's the right syntax.

Or do you need to capture the value for some other reason than assertions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with Mockito. You may rewrite your code to make it "unit testatble" or much better by writing the test first and the code after in a TDD approach.

However if for some reasons you can't modify your code, it is possible to use [PowerMock features](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13). For example `PowerMockito.whenNew` will allow you to provide a mock of `A`. But this approach is not recommended.